# TableHeader of Material UI does not make the content bold

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI to create a table. The documentation shows that the TableHeader component should make the text inside itself bold, but this is not happening in my project. I did not apply any style myself and I did not override the default Material UI theme. I just copied [this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/htvjz?file=/demo.js:1358-1371) inside my project but I can't see the bold header. I don't even know how to debug this, the style is applied in the browser, I checked with the inspector, but it does nothing to the displayed text. What could I do?

Comment: Have you compared the font-weight (Elements -> Styles tab) of the header in your local version with the one from the codesandbox?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I actually figured out. I just had to import all the variants of the font I was using (Roboto in my case) from Google Fonts.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />` from https://mui.com/components/typography/
It's not required but they should really emphasize it more in the Getting Started steps.

Comment: For people using Next.js with the App Router, you can import the font using an unamed import in JavaScript/TypeScript with the correct fonts https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/#roboto-font (in your `layout.tsx` or `page.tsx`).

Answer (score 1):

### Investigate the default library style

One way is to console the theme like:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  console.log(theme);
  return {
    ...
  };
});
```

Second way is to check by incpect the element with the dev tools and check for the default styles

Third way is to go and see where it's define in the library:

Here we can see that the fontWeight of TableCell head is "fontWeightMedium"

[image]

And here we see what the value of "fontWeightMedium"

[image]

---

### (Old answer) How to override the styles:

In your codesandbox the default font-weight is 500.
and you can override it like this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-driscoll-n9yyw

I add this override:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {
    minWidth: 650,
    "& .MuiTableCell-head": {
      fontWeight: 700
    }
  }
});
```

In material ui a better way is to update all the overrides in one place - theme:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const theme = createTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        fontSize: '1rem',
      },
    },
  },
});

export default function GlobalThemeOverride() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button>font-size: 1rem</Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

(https://material-ui.com/customization/components/)

Comment: Yes, I know I can style the header myself, I was just wondering why I can't see the default style

Comment: I actually solved it, apparently I had to manually import all the Roboto styles from google font... I thought that Material UI did also that, but it seems not.